# is there any dynamic xml parsing

Tags: iphone

how to parse if xml attributes changes...'

for example

```
<Root>
<child name="", age="",phone="",address=""/>
</Root>
```

this is my first request from iphone through webserver.... i parsed above xml...

after that when i request the same url  .. which is updated  now it my xml child tag changes.

```
<Root>
<child name="",age="",phone="",address="",office="",mobile="",location=""/>
</Root>
```

extra three attributes added..

what to do with this approach .. any example please send... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)startParsingForSendFriendRequest:(NSString *)userID  Friend:(NSString*)friendID  
{

    NSString *urlString =[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"http:///user_id=%@&friend_id=%@",userID,friendID];

    ////NSLog(@"urlString : %@",urlString);
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:xmlURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0]autorelease];

    NSURLResponse *returnedResponse = nil;
    NSError *returnedError = nil;
    NSData *itemData  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&returnedResponse error:&returnedError];
    //NSString *itemString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[itemData bytes] length:[itemData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];

    //NSLog(@"itemString : %@",itemString);


    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:itemData];       
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    [xmlParser parse];

}



- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    ////NSLog(@"parserDidStartDocument");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    ////NSLog(@"parseErrorOccurred");
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading data" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
    [errorAlert release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    //NSLog(@"didStartElement");
//  NSLog(@"elementName : %@",elementName);
//  NSLog(@"namespaceURI : %@",namespaceURI);
//  NSLog(@"qualifiedName : %@",qualifiedName);
    NSLog(@"attributeDict : %@",attributeDict);

    [registerNewArr addObject:attributeDict];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    ////NSLog(@"foundCharacters");



}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    ////NSLog(@"didEndElement");

}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    if ([[[registerNewArr objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"Transaction"]isEqualToString:@"loginxml"]) 
    {
        [(WakeuuupLoginScreenVC *)obj getRegisterResult:registerNewArr];
    }


}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [registerNewArr release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```